# Проектирование базы данных. Что выбрать столбцы или строки?

Tags: база-данных, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

Это мой первый вопрос. Не судите строго, но готов к критике.
Итак суть проблемы.

Есть пул объектов. Объекты принадлежат разным модификациям. Например модель 310: *Об310-1* , *Oб310-2*, модель 312: *Об312-1*, модель 530: *Об530-1*, *Об530-2*.

Каждый объект содержит одинаковое количество групп атрибутов. Например пусть будет 3 группы *DS*, *HS*, *GS*.

Количество атрибутов может быть разным (от 150 до 300 штук на объект). При этом есть атрибуты приоритетные для системы (нужны для принятия решений) и есть не критичные (нужны для построения графиков и отчетов).  Пул данных от объектов приходит одним пакетом, соответственно для всех атрибутов конкретного объекта можно установить одинаковый *TIMESTAMP*

Необходимо хранить значения всех атрибутов из всех групп всех объектов всех модификаций.

Есть несколько вариантов построения таблицы\таблиц.

1. Одна таблица. ID, TIMESTAMP, Имя составное(Объект_Группа_Атрибут) и значение атрибута. Пишется все подряд. ***Много записей***.
2. Вариант 1 измененный. Для каждого объекта своя таблица. ***Много записей***.
3. Для каждого объекта отдельная таблица вида:
   TIMESTAMP Атрибут 1, Атрибут 2, ... Атрибут Х. ***Много столбцов***
   Про нормализацию знаю.
   Сейчас этап разработки. На попробовать. Но в будущем система будет расширяться. Можете помочь советом какой из вариантов лучше выбрать?
   Ну понеслась

@Akina. Еще раз просмотрел структуру базы. Да согласен, что модель EAV для нашей ситуации оптимальный вариант. Возможно я не правильно изначально задал вопрос.

На одном из форумов (https://www.sql.ru/forum/1174811/pattern-eav), надеюсь что это Вы, было упомянуто >...я пошёл по пути "одна таблица, но несколько полей". Я честно не ожидал такого быстрого ответа. Но вот моральный выбор между "одна сущность один атрибут одно значение" или "одна сущность много значений атрибутов" вынудил обратиться к сообществу и узнать у него:

все-таки можно модель EAV немного модернизировать в своих целях добавив несколько сотен столбцов и на что это может повлиять?

Comment: *Про нормализацию знаю.* Тогда откуда возник вопрос? Если Вы проделали полный анализ предметной области, у Вас должна остаться только одна схема. И весь выбор должен свестись к вопросу - делать таблицы групп атрибутов разреженными, EAV, или хранить наборы атрибутов сериализованными. А это уже определяется тем, какие действия будут с ними выполняться. В первую очередь - будут ли наборы и их данные изменяться, и будет вестись индивидуальная или групповая обработка, а также выбранной СУБД. В общем, пока для осмысленного ответа недостаточно данных имхо.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - можете в одной таблице храните ключевые параметры по которым будете искать, сортировать, ключи на др. таблицы. А данные для постраения графиков храните в формате JSON в поле CLOB желательно в отдельной таблице, чтоб оно не тормозило обработку ключевых полей при запросах. Так вы обеспечите быстрый поиск по основным атрибутам, и у вас не будет кучи записей.